# Huge increase in allocated memory on activity start then back to normal

Tags: android, out-of-memory

Using DDMS on eclipse, I have noticed that the allocated memory increases from 18 MB to about 53 MB in a second when a new activity is being loaded, and then it jumps back to normal 23-28 MB when it finishes loading the activity.

My app is a dressing up game, and so it includes a lot of images. However, the size of all the images doesn't reach 5 MB. Since it gets back to the normal 23-28 MB, I believe there are no leaks.

onCreate is used mainly for findViewById of all the Views.

Sometimes I am getting an error:

```
08-16 16:16:56.160: E/AndroidRuntime(22614): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 16:16:56.160: E/AndroidRuntime(22614): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com......}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #243: Error inflating class <unknown>
...
08-16 16:16:56.160: E/AndroidRuntime(22614): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #243: Error inflating class <unknown>
...
08-16 16:16:56.160: E/AndroidRuntime(22614): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
08-16 16:16:56.160: E/AndroidRuntime(22614): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-16 16:16:56.160: E/AndroidRuntime(22614):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
```

Notice the OutOfMemoryError.

What can I do?

Comment: `However, the size of all the images doesn't reach 5 MB` you mean on the file system? Well bitmaps in memory aren't compressed, that means they are usually way bigger... 5MB in pngs is not really small...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the memory spike when starting the app is due to the OS decompressing the resources you are using in one of your layouts. This is also probably the cause of the OutOfMemoryError exception.

Review the resources (images etc.) that you are using in your initial layout and make sure they are not to big.